# how to identify and correctly wire a new light

Tags: electrical

if there is a copper ground wire currently hanging down, can I just marry it and cap it together to the silver grounding wire that the new light came with??

Comment: Can you post a close-up photo of the box you're trying to install the light to?

Answer (score 1):

If the "silver" wire goes directly to the frame of the light putting it with the bare copper is the correct thing to do. Then connect the black to black and white to white and you can say "let there be light".